# Signing fails when trying to publish to Maven Central using Sonatype nexus (gradle-nexus.publish-plugin)

Tags: gradle, nexus, publishing, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to publish my library to Maven Central. I already set it up over at Sonatype Nexus, and now I'm trying to hook up Gradle to it (this library depends on Minecraft Forge, so using Maven isn't an option).

I saw that there was a plugin created called [Gradle Nexus Publish Plugin](https://github.com/gradle-nexus/publish-plugin) and thought I could use it to make publishing easier.

Using the `publishAllPublicationsToSonatypeRepository` Gradle task, I could publish a repo to Nexus;
But once I call `closeSonatypeStagingRepository`, it fails with the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':signMavenPublication'.
> Could not read PGP secret key

Cause: premature end of stream in PartialInputStream
```

Now, I added a `println` to see what key Gradle reads from `signingKey`, and turns out that no matter what I put there, it always retrieves the same key, even if I put in an invalid key (this is an altered key):

```
lQWGBGByDfwBDADB5pWxgBT04U0bDIv/Pv0zDEYqKXt2Dubj3RcvCDAveel3eYFt
```

(The password is being updated though)

Why is this happening?

This is my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
import net.minecraftforge.gradle.common.util.ModConfig
import net.minecraftforge.gradle.common.util.RunConfig
import net.minecraftforge.gradle.userdev.UserDevExtension
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

// BuildScript
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven(url = "https://maven.minecraftforge.net/")
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath(group = "net.minecraftforge.gradle", name = "ForgeGradle", version = "4.1.+")
    }
}

plugins {
    idea
    id("io.github.gradle-nexus.publish-plugin") version "1.0.0"
    `java-library`
    `maven-publish`
    signing
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.0"
}
apply(plugin = "net.minecraftforge.gradle")

// Config -> Minecraft
val forgeVersion: String by extra
val minecraftVersion: String by extra
val kffVersion: String by extra
val modVersion: String by extra

// JVM Info
println(
    """
        Java: ${System.getProperty("java.version")} 
        JVM: ${System.getProperty("java.vm.version")} (${System.getProperty("java.vendor")}) 
        Arch: ${System.getProperty("os.arch")}
    """.trimIndent()
)

// Minecraft
configure<UserDevExtension> {
    mappings("official", minecraftVersion)

    @Suppress("SpellCheckingInspection")
    accessTransformer(file("src/main/resources/META-INF/accesstransformer.cfg"))

    runs(closureOf<NamedDomainObjectContainer<RunConfig>> {
        create("client") {
            workingDirectory(file("run"))

            taskName = "client"

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            property("forge.logging.markers", "SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP")

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            property("forge.logging.console.level", "debug")

            mods(closureOf<NamedDomainObjectContainer<ModConfig>> {
                create("loottables") {
                    source(sourceSets["main"])
                }
            })
        }

        create("server") {
            workingDirectory(file("run"))

            taskName = "server"

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            property("forge.logging.markers", "SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP")

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            property("forge.logging.console.level", "debug")

            mods(closureOf<NamedDomainObjectContainer<ModConfig>> {
                create("loottables") {
                    source(sourceSets["main"])
                }
            })
        }

        create("data") {
            workingDirectory(file("run"))

            taskName = "datagen"

            // Recommended logging data for a userdev environment
            property("forge.logging.markers", "SCAN,REGISTRIES,REGISTRYDUMP")

            // Recommended logging level for the console
            property("forge.logging.console.level", "debug")

            // Specify the mod id for data generation, where to output the resulting resource, and where to look for existing resources.
            args(
                "--mod",
                "loottables",
                "--all",
                "--output",
                file("src/generated/resources/"),
                "--existing",
                file("src/main/resources/")
            )

            mods(closureOf<NamedDomainObjectContainer<ModConfig>> {
                create("loottables") {
                    source(sourceSets["main"])
                }
            })
        }
    })
}

// Minecraft Dependency
// Note: Due to the way kotlin gradle works we need to define the minecraft dependency after we configure Minecraft
dependencies {
    "minecraft"(group = "net.minecraftforge", name = "forge", version = "$minecraftVersion-$forgeVersion")
    implementation(group = "thedarkcolour", name = "kotlinforforge", version = "latest.release")
    testImplementation(
        group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin",
        name = "kotlin-test-junit5",
        version = kotlin.coreLibrariesVersion
    )
}

repositories {
    maven {
        name = "kotlinforforge"
        url = uri("https://thedarkcolour.github.io/KotlinForForge/")
    }
}

// Setup
project.group = "com.theonlytails"
project.version = modVersion
base.archivesBaseName = "loottables"

// Sets the toolchain to compile against OpenJDK 8
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(8))
        vendor.set(JvmVendorSpec.ADOPTOPENJDK)
    }
}

// Finalize the jar by re-obfuscating
tasks.named<Jar>("jar") {
    // Manifest
    manifest {
        attributes(
            "Specification-Title" to "LootTables",
            "Specification-Vendor" to "TheOnlyTails",
            "Specification-Version" to "1",
            "Implementation-Title" to "LootTables",
            "Implementation-Version" to project.version,
            "Implementation-Vendor" to "TheOnlyTails",
            "Implementation-Timestamp" to DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(Instant.now()),
            "FMLModType" to "LIBRARY"
        )
    }

    @Suppress("SpellCheckingInspection")
    finalizedBy("reobfJar")
}

// Publishing to maven central
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            groupId = "com.theonlytails"
            artifactId = "loottables"
            version = modVersion

            from(components["java"])

            pom {
                name.set("LootTables")
                description.set("A Kotlin DSL for creating loot tables in Minecraft Forge mods")
                url.set("https://github.com/theonlytails/loottables")

                properties.set(mapOf("project.build.sourceEncoding" to "UTF-8"))

                licenses {
                    license {
                        name.set("MIT License")
                        url.set("https://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php")
                        distribution.set("repo")
                    }
                }

                developers {
                    developer {
                        id.set("theonlytails")
                        name.set("TheOnlyTails")
                        url.set("https://theonlytails.com/")
                    }
                }

                issueManagement {
                    url.set("https://github.com/theonlytails/loottables/issues")
                    system.set("GitHub Issues")
                }

                scm {
                    connection.set("scm:git:git:github.com/theonlytails/loottables.git")
                    developerConnection.set("scm:git:git@github.com:theonlytails/loottables.git")
                    url.set("https://github.com/theonlytails/loottables")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

java {
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}

signing {
    val signingPassword: String? by extra
    val signingKey: String? by extra

    println(signingKey) // this is for debbuging purposes only, I'm obviously going to remove this once done
    println(signingPassword)

    useInMemoryPgpKeys(
        signingKey ?: throw GradleException("Couldn't find a signing password"),
        signingPassword ?: throw GradleException("Couldn't find a signing key")
    )

    sign(publishing.publications["maven"])
}

nexusPublishing {
    repositories {
        sonatype {
            nexusUrl.set(uri("https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/"))
            snapshotRepositoryUrl.set(uri("https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"))

            username.set(System.getenv("MAVEN_USERNAME"))
            password.set(System.getenv("MAVEN_PASSWORD"))
        }
    }
}

// Testing
tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```